# IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/ in django

Tags: mysql, django, innodb, ubuntu-14.04, myisam

I have just deployed my django site using apache on an ubuntu 14.04 server.
The site is being accessed. But when i signup as a user into it, it creates the user but is unable to create the user profile which is in a one to one relationship with myuser. Also, I am using a custom user model. the error it throws on signup is:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ilog_prod_db`.`myuserprofile_myuserprofile`, CONSTRAINT `myuserprofile_myuserp_myuser_id_6ad6f704425ed359_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`myuser_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))
```

The point is that, on my dev machine(windows7), the website is working perfectly fine with the same code. Also, the settings of database is exactly the same, ie in both places i have used InnoDB as the database engine for the database.

What can be the problem. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://www.industrylogger.com/accounts/signup/

Django Version: 1.7.2
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'enterprise',
 'accounts',
 'nodes',
 'message',
 'myuserprofile',
 'enterprise_profile',
 'activities',
 'search',
 'imagekit')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/sp/webapps/ilog_dev/accounts/views.py" in signup
  24.                                          password=password,)
File "/home/sp/webapps/ilog_dev/accounts/models.py" in create_myuser
  93.         user.save(using=self._db)
File "/home/sp/webapps/ilog_dev/accounts/models.py" in save
  152.             super(MyUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  589.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  626.                                    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  198.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/home/sp/webapps/ilog_dev/myuserprofile/models.py" in create_user_profile
  121.         MyUserProfile.objects.create(myuser=instance)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  372.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  589.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  617.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  698.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  731.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  921.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  920.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py" in execute
  135.         return self._execute_wrapper(self.cursor.execute, query, args)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py" in _execute_wrapper
  121.                         utils.IntegrityError(err.msg), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  658.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py" in _execute_wrapper
  115.             return method(query, args)
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py" in execute
  507.                 self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py" in cmd_query
  722.         result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
File "/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py" in _handle_result
  640.             raise errors.get_exception(packet)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/
Exception Value: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ilog_prod_db`.`myuserprofile_myuserprofile`, CONSTRAINT `myuserprofile_myuserp_myuser_id_6ad6f704425ed359_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`myuser_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))
```

Comment: Try to write minmal code that reproduces your problem. It's hard to debug this issue without any code.

Comment: Try changing the database name and then run `python manage.py syncdb` to build the  tables. If it works after that, then it's an issue with the database schema

Comment: in my dev machine i just tried to change the name of database and created a whole new database. and even the it is running fine there. and the code on my ubuntu server is just a git clone of the code on dev machine.

Comment: @ marcel I will update the question with the traceback. see if it helps. becuse for showing the code, i will have to update a hel lot of codes. please look into it

Comment: @Basic & @ Marcel Meiber , i thing the problem is something originating from mysql tables and database schema rather than the django codes. please suggest something

Comment: @sprksh I found a script for checking your InnoDBs constraints on mysql.com you can wget it from this adress http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PRtJFR0j . Ofcourse this will only find inconsistencies, you'll have to figure out where the error comes from yourself.

Comment: I have no idea why, but just creating my database again solved the problem

Comment: @sprksh Because your django model and sql schema were out of sync

Answer (score 1):

From the comments on the question, it looks like your django model and database schema are out of sync. If you can, just delete the database and recreate. If you have important data in there...

**First make a backup of your production database**

Depending on which version of django you're using, database synchronisation behaves differently.

#### Django <= 1.6

The `python manage.py syncdb` command can be used to add any missing schema information to your database. If your problem stems from the fact that you've added new tables or fields to your model / that constraints have been deleted, this might fix the schema.

It will not remove any old fields or migrate any data, so there's a good chance you'll need to do some manual editing afterwards.

#### Django >= 1.7

1.7 introduced the new `python manage.py migrate` ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/)) command which is more intelligent. As your model changes, migrations are created. When an old database needs to be brought inline with a new model, the migrations are applied to the database.

This is far more flexible and allows database versions to be upgraded/downgraded as required.

The downside is that you need to have made migrations as you go (or create them manually afterwards). See the documentation for more information

In either case, if the model is too far out of sync or you don't have the appropriate migrations, you're going to need to do some manual work to get the data into the state required by django.

Comment: But changing the database helped me for the first signup only. When i tried to signup as 2nd test user, the same error was shown, I even tried changing the tables to MyISAM, even that was showing error and could not be done. Now to make it work, I had to change the default database engine to myISAM and create the database again. Now its working, but i cant continue this way for long. Suggest me what should i do in this case. Please suggest me the appropriate.

Comment: also, wanted to add that the same conversion on windows 7 dev machine works perfectly. i cant understand where the problem starts and what are its implications.

Comment: Ok, let's compare your model and your database table. Can you please edit your question to include the output from: `EXPLAIN` for the 2 user tables in mysql ([Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)) and the 2 user models? Also, which version of django are you using?